# Why don't multiprotocol transmitters work with Radiolink receivers?

Tags: t16, receiver, multiprotocol-module, compatibility

I have a Jumper T16 and am wondering why it or any other multiprotocol transmitters don't work with Radiolink receivers. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jumper T16 multiprotocol module doesn't support Radiolink receivers, as you know. This is because the module doesn't have any hardware to recreate the Radiolink protocol.

As can be seen on the product [listing for the T16 Pro here](https://hobbycool.com/products/jumper-t16-opentx-multi-protocol-radio-transmitter),

> RF Chip Data
>
> Cypress Semiconductor CYRF6936: DSM/DSMX, Walkera Devo
>
> Texas Instruments CC2500: FrSky, Futaba SFHSS
>
> Amiccom A7105: FlySky, FlySky AFHDS2A, Hubsan
>
> Nordic Semiconductor NRF24L01: HiSky, Syma, ASSAN and most other Chinese models

The reason for this is likely either that:

- The necessary hardware to create the Radiolink protocol either isn't available to third parties or isn't cost-effective to license
- Radiolink receivers aren't popular enough to warrant the R&D required to reverse-engineer the protocol or include in a radio